# Getting difference between datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i am trying to get a difference between two columns of datetime in my dataframe, which looks like this:

```
          Time 1                       Time 2          Hours 
2019-02-24 09:35:49 2019-02-24 09:18:47 0
2019-02-24 09:43:45 2019-02-24 09:18:47 0
2019-02-24 21:52:25 2019-02-24 09:18:47 12
2019-02-25 22:04:11 2019-02-24 21:52:25 0
2019-02-25 22:49:53 2019-02-24 21:52:25 0
2019-02-25 12:52:32 2019-02-24 21:52:25 15
2019-02-25 00:53:57 2019-02-25 12:52:32 12
2019-02-25 02:47:47 2019-02-25 00:53:57 1
```

I am using the following code:

```py
delta = Time 2 - Time 1
totalSeconds = delta.seconds
Hours = divmod(totalSeconds, 3600)[0]
df.loc[index,'Hours'] = Hours
```

But the problem is that this code is not taking change of date into account.In line 4 of my data, the values of date-time are a day apart but its still showing difference of hours as 0 hours because i reckon it is only subtracting time and not considering change of date.

What should i change in my code, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small demo uses row 4 of your data.

IN:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time1':['2019-02-25 22:04:11'], 'Time2':['2019-02-24 21:52:25']})
df = df.applymap(pd.to_datetime)
df['Hours'] = (df.Time1 - df.Time2).dt.total_seconds() // 3600
```

OUT:

```
| Time1               | Time2               | Hours |
|---------------------|---------------------|-------|
| 2019-02-25 22:04:11 | 2019-02-24 21:52:25 | 24.0  |
```

Answer (score 0):

use `delta.total_seconds()` instead of `delta.seconds`

seconds is the number of seconds within a day. Total_seconds give you the entire timedelta converted to seconds, it could be more than 1 day.

```
totalSeconds = delta.total_seconds()
```

Comment: is your dataframe in datetime type ? `df['Time 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time 1']);df['Time 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time 2']);delta = df['Time 2'] - df['Time 1'];totalSeconds = delta.total_seconds()`

Comment: Also, i notice your Time 1 is greater than Time 2, u might wanna do `delta = df['Time 1'] - df['Time 2']`

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.